# List<Tuple<T1,T2>> as DataSource for GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview, tuples

I'd like to add a `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>` as `DataSource` for my `GridView`.

"Then do it!"

Yeah, that's not really the problem, the problem is accessing the values inside the GridView.

Here's my Code:

```
List<Tuple<Group, string>> userGroups = Util.PrepareGroups((string[][])Session["userGroups"]);
            gridGroups.DataSource = userGroups;
            gridGroups.DataBind();
```

Throws an exception at `DataBind`, telling me that Item1.Name doesn't exist, speaking of this, here's my markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridGroups" CssClass="grid gridGroups" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField meta:resourcekey="gridGroupsName" DataField="Item1.Name" />
            <asp:BoundField meta:resourcekey="gridGroupsFunction" DataField="Item2" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Needless to say, `Item1` is the Group and `Name`is a `string`-Property.
He (yes, he, my IDE is called Bob) obviously doesn't find Item1.Name, is there any way to escape the `.`?

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: Bob?.. You code in [Microsoft Bob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bob)?..

Comment: No, I write my code using Bob 2010 Professional!

Comment: As opposed to those slacker Bobs who dropped out of art school...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribe to the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event in your code-behind, that will fire for each row that is bound and you can use the arguments supplied to the event to get at the current data item - you'll find it easier to get at your values that way than trying to mess around with the databinding syntax etc.

(ps - remember to check the rowtype property in your event handler, that's an easy mistake to make - you'll get unexpected results/errors if you're trying to access the data object for a header/footer row! - the link above has some code that demonstrates this)

Comment: Vote's locked, sorry. Also clicking on the Up-Arrow again would remove it, clicking the Down-Arrow actually changes it into a -1, and we wouldn't want that, would we!?